# Javascript cypress test runtime behavior

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, cypress

I think this is a common Javascript question, rather than cypress test, yet I am not sure.

So I have a a UI in web, which will show a text message like `found 3234 matches`, I would like to use cypress to extract the number 3234, then on next page, I will input 3234 in another input box.

My code is like

```
const MATCHING_MESSAGE = '[data-cy=matchingMessages]';

let count = 0;
cy.get(MATCHING_MESSAGE)
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    const pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
    count = text.match(pattern).pop();
    console.log({count1: count});
  })

// move to next page

console.log({count2: count});
if (count > 0) {
  // input count
} else {
  // input a min number like 5
}
```

However, when I execute this. the browser console is like

```
log: count2: 0
log: count1: 3234
```

Then the next page is always behaving like count is `0`

1. I know this is execution order issue, but why log `count2: 0` execute so fast like this get logged even before I moved to the second page.
2. Also, what knowledge I am missing for JS, to get more of this execution order and promise issue.
3. Is there a way I can enforce the execution order?

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `cy.then()` command as a wrapper around the code that uses `count`.

This will make sure the value has been evaluated before using it.

```js
const MATCHING_MESSAGE = '[data-cy=matchingMessages]';

let count = null;    // null is not a valid value, so it's obvious if the
                     // evaluation is 0 or 3243 - or not actually happened

// this block is Cypress queue code, so it will evaluate later when the queue runs
cy.get(MATCHING_MESSAGE)
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    const pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
    count = text.match(pattern).pop()
    console.log({count1: count});
  })

// move to next page

cy.then(() => {

  // inside then(): this block of code also runs on the Cypress queue
  // so now you get the correct ordering of execution

  console.log({count2: count});

  // parseInt since you do a numeric compare
  if (parseInt(count) > 0) {
    // input count
  } else {
    // input a min number like 5
  }
})
```

---

**Page refresh**

The part that does `// move to next page` may refresh the browser. If so the `count` variable will be erased altogether.

If you find that is the case, add the count to the Cypress environment instead.

```js
const MATCHING_MESSAGE = '[data-cy=matchingMessages]';

cy.get(MATCHING_MESSAGE)
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    const pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
    count = text.match(pattern).pop()
    console.log({count1: count});
    Cypress.env('count', count)         // save to environment store
  })

// move to next page

cy.then(() => {

  // inside then(): this block of code also runs on the Cypress queue
  // so now you get the correct ordering of execution

  cont count = Cypress.env('count')   // restore the value

  console.log({count2: count});

  // parseInt since you do a numeric compare
  if (parseInt(count) > 0) {
    // input count
  } else {
    // input a min number like 5
  }
})
```